# dplyr::select_ behavior with factor

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I use dplyr::select to select columns of my dataset. I observe an interesting phenomenon about select_ with factor and want to ask why this happens.

I have a 4x3 data frame and want to select column "a" and "c"

```
x <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 3) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c("a","b", "c"))

# works, output: "a" "c"
x %>% select_(.dots = c("a", "c")) %>% colnames()

# change the search term to a factor, output wrong columns: "a" "b"
x %>% select_(.dots = as.factor(c("a", "c"))) %>% colnames()
```

Could you kindly give a hint why this happens?

Comment: Look at output of `as.numeric(as.factor(c("a", "b")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `factor` is stored internally as integer.  So, it is coercing to integer, resulting in 1, 2 and `select` selects the 1st two.  In general, the `select_` with `.dots` method is outdated.  We can use quosures or `select_at`, `select_if` etc

```
x %>%
   select_at(vars(a, c))
```

Or

```
x %>% 
   select(a, c)
```

Or

```
x %>% 
  select(!!! quos(a, c))
```